# Fusing two variables into one in R

Tags: r

Let's create a dataset:

```
hospital <- c("Boston", "New York", "California")
patients <- c(100, 150, 350)
costs <- c(3.0, 3.1, 2.5)
df <- data.frame(hospital, patients, costs)
The dataset we created is called df:
```

df

```
hospital patients costs 
Boston        100   3.0 
New York      150   3.1 
California    350   2.5
```

My aim is to at some point of my analysis consider Boston and New York as the same variable:

```
hospital patients costs 
BosNY         100   3.0 
BosNY         150   3.1 
California    350   2.5
```

How can I do this in R? Thanks!

Comment: This is a question about programming, not about statistics. Stackoverflow might be the better place to host this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mapvalues` from `plyr` will do the job.

```
require(plyr)
hospital <- c("Boston", "New York", "California")
patients <- c(100, 150, 350)
costs <- c(3.0, 3.1, 2.5)
df <- data.frame(hospital, patients, costs)
df$hospital <- mapvalues(
  df$hospital,
  from=c("Boston", "New York"),
  to=c("BosNY", "BosNY")
)
```

```
> df
    hospital patients costs
1      BosNY      100   3.0
2      BosNY      150   3.1
3 California      350   2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple `ifelse` statement:

```
hospital <- c("Boston", "New York", "California")
patients <- c(100, 150, 350)
costs <- c(3.0, 3.1, 2.5)
df <- data.frame(hospital, patients, costs)

df$hospital2 <- ifelse(df$hospital %in% c("Boston", "New York"), 
                       yes = "BosNY", no = as.character(df$hospital))
```

Comment: This is my favourite because it keeps the original column, however, as this is not what I asked, it wouldn't be fair. Thank you so much! I can't vote up because I am new :(

Comment: No worries. As long as you pick any answer everything is good. Pro tip: Look at stackoverflow as a question and answer site about programming, not so much as a place to gain points/reputation.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

We could use `recode` from `dyplr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(hospital = recode(hospital, "Boston" = "BosNY", "New York" = "BosNY"))
```

Output:

```
    hospital patients costs
1      BosNY      100   3.0
2      BosNY      150   3.1
3 California      350   2.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the cities by matching based on a character vector containing their names (using `%in%` operator) and replace them using an `ifelse()`.

```
city_names <- c("Boston", "New York")
df$hospital <- ifelse(df$hospital %in% city_names, "BosNY", df$hospital)

df

#     hospital patients costs
# 1      BosNY      100   3.0
# 2      BosNY      150   3.1
# 3 California      350   2.5
```

Comment: Hii @BuddyBob, Thanks for your comment. I have added some explanation and edited the code for readability. Hope these are more useful.